# Deploy docker container using gitlab ci docker-in-docker setup

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm currently trying to setup a gitlab ci pipeline. I've chosen to [go with the Docker-in-Docker setup](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-executor).
I got my ci pipeline to build and push the docker image to the registry of gitlab but I cannot seem deploy it using the following configuration:

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: docker:stable
services:
- docker:dind

stages:
- build
- deploy

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  TEST_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/user/repo.nl:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  RELEASE_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/user/repo.nl:release

before_script:
- docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
- docker info

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
  - build
  script:
  - docker build --pull -t $TEST_IMAGE .
  - docker push $TEST_IMAGE
  only:
  - branches

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
  - deploy
  script:
  - docker pull $TEST_IMAGE
  - docker tag $TEST_IMAGE $RELEASE_IMAGE
  - docker push $RELEASE_IMAGE
  - docker run -d --name "review-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" -p "80:80" $RELEASE_IMAGE
  only:
  - master
  when: manual
```

When I run the deploy action I actually get the following feedback in my log, but when I go check the server there is no container running.

```
$ docker run -d --name "review-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" -p "80:80" $RELEASE_IMAGE
7bd109a8855e985cc751be2eaa284e78ac63a956b08ed8b03d906300a695a375
Job succeeded
```

I have no clue as to what I am forgetting here. Am I right to expect this method to be correct for deploying containers? What am I missing / doing wrong?

**tldr**: *Want to deploy images into production using gitlab ci and docker-in-docker setup, job succeeds but there is no container. Goal is to have a running container on host after deployment.*

Answer (score 1):

Found out that I needed to include the docker socket in the gitlab-runner configuration as well, and not only have it available in the container. 
By adding `--docker-volumes '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'` and removing `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2375` I was able to connect to docker on my host system and spawn sibling containers.

Comment: I'm faced something similar. I want to deployed using shell executor. where I suposse I could add --docker-volumes?. on config.toml? How?

Comment: Hi @Darwin. The docker volumes need to be on the docker-compose file if you are using it, otherwise on the docker run command. But also in the config.toml as     volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]